# Spark Job UI - time/duration values under the name of a step

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

I have a simple question - what are the times at the top of WholeStageCodegen rectangles in the Spark UI? Is it a processing time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the sum of the computation time of tasks composing the step.

The 3 other values in parentheses are minimum, median and maximum values of computation time spent by the tasks.

- the fastest task took 64ms to complete
- if you order the tasks by computation time, the one in the middle took 147ms to complete
- the slowest took 1.3 sec to complete